# How to write unit test case using Xunit and moq framework for this method

Tags: c#, xunit

How to write unit test case using Xunit and moq framework for this method

```
 public async Task<View?> GetViewCode(string id, string code)
        {
            using var queryFactory = _queryFactory();
            var row = await queryFactory.Query(TableName)
                .Where("Id", id)
                .Where("Code", code)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync<Row>();
            return row?.ToView();
        }
```

How to mock these line using mock framework.
I am working on sql kata first time, can any one help me with writhing test cases for this code

Comment: 1. make sure the class containing this method using dependency injection, so that you can mock queryFactory. 
2. create a unit test where you create an object from the class, pass the queryFactory in as a mocked object at the initialization.
3. set up moq to return different results from the mocked queryFactory object. 
4. that is the basic pattern, plenty of possibility for unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider an interface IHelper has this method's definition.

```
    [Fact]    
    public void TestMethodName
{
 var interfaceMoq = new Mock<IHelper>();
 interfaceMoq.Setup(x => x.GetViewCode(It.Is<string>(x => 
 !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x), It.Is<string>(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))))
 .ReturnsAsync(response);
 // Assert Statement
 }
```

x is used to provide validation for inputs. There are various other options. You should check them out.
Here, the response is your predefined response or data model. And you can choose an Assert statement based on your requirements.

Package References:
using Moq;
using Xunit;

Self Promotion:
https://medium.com/@__hungrywolf/unit-testing-with-xunit-part-1-introduction-a3cde7aecb3